# Keyboard media keys (play, pause etc) don't work while Excel 2013 is active

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

Excel 2013 appears to "swallow" these keys: whenever it's active, play/pause and similar keyboard keys don't work at all. Activate any other application and they work again.

Is there a known fix?

I've already tried Google. Either this problem is unique to me, or people haven't posted about it. If you have Excel 2013 and multimedia keys on your keyboard, it would be cool if you could test whether they operate while Excel 2013 is active.

Comment: What have you researched or tried to resolve this on your own so far? What keys are you talking about? Is this a laptop or a special keyboard?

Comment: I don’t understand why this question is being downvoted?... I don’t have this problem myself, but surely this is a perfectly valid question?...

Comment: First, I didn't down vote. Second, I am asking for clarity because there are MANY keyboard layouts and types which have media keys; especially laptops. Third, by your reputation, you should know better than to ask a vague question and expect us to read your mind. Lastly, remember we are here to help you. So, asking you what you've done already is a way of avoiding the "already tried that" replies to everything we suggest. Nasty, condescending comments will not get you any help.

Comment: @CharlieRB apologies about the false accusation then.

Comment: @romkyns I have Excel 2013 and a logitech K800. I just tested all media keys in foobar2000 while Excel was the active window. All media keys worked as they should. Maybe reinstall Office? Is there any VBA running in the background? Maybe an VBA add-in. Are there custom shortcuts set up for macros?

Comment: I agree with @nixda try running excel in safe mode and see if the problem persists